# Can/Should I access multiple device registers via a single pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, stm32

I am currently writing in C for the STM32F446RE (ARM compiler), and since I want to gain experience in embedded programming I am not using any libraries. For my initialization, I was wondering whether or not it would be a good idea to access registers by incrementing one pointer by the offset of that register from the peripheral base.

```
    void I2C_Init(void)
    {
        volatile uint32_t *reg_ptr = (uint32_t *) GPIOB_LOC;
        *(reg_ptr + GPIOB_MODE_OFFSET) &= ~((0xFU<<16) | (0xFU<<20));   //clear before updating
        *(reg_ptr + GPIOB_MODE_OFFSET) |= ((0xAU<<16) | (0xAU<<20));        //set pins 8, 9, 10, 11 to alt func
        *(reg_ptr + GPIOB_OTYPE_OFFSET) &= ~(0xFU<<8);  //no types
        *(reg_ptr + GPIOB_OSPEED_OFFSET) &= ~((0xFU<<16) | (0xFU<<20)); //clear before updating
        *(reg_ptr + GPIOB_OSPEED_OFFSET) |= ((0x5U<<16) | (0x5U<<20));      //set to normal speed (will get overriden by alt func)
        *(reg_ptr + GPIOB_PUPD_OFFSET) &= ~((0xFU<<16) | (0xFU<<20));       //no pull up or pull down
        *(reg_ptr + GPIOB_AFH_OFFSET) &= ~0xFFFFU;  //clear before updating
        *(reg_ptr + GPIOB_AFH_OFFSET) |= 0x4444U;       //set pins 8, 9, 10, 11 to alt func 4 (i2c1 & i2c2 SCL and SDA respectively)
    }
```

In my header file:

```
    #define GPIOB_LOC       0x40020400UL    //base
    #define GPIOB_MODE_OFFSET (0x00)
    #define GPIOB_OTYPE_OFFSET (0x04)
    #define GPIOB_OSPEED_OFFSET (0x08)
    #define GPIOB_PUPD_OFFSET (0x0C)
    #define GPIOB_AFH_OFFSET (0x24)
```

Is this practice unsafe? Is there a better, more commonly accepted method of accessing multiple device registers without the overhead of creating a pointer for each specific register?

Thanks guys! This is my first post, so also let me know if there's anything I can do to improve my question or any more info that would be helpful.

Comment: Sure. The usual scheme is to define a structure matching the register layout and set up a pointer to its base address though, which is equivalent but type-safe and rather nicer to work with.

Comment: You must be careful when adding an offset to an address (pointer?) in C. If you add 4 to a pointer-to-32bit-value the compiler will add 16. Pointer arithmetic works in the same way as array element indexing, that is, it takes account of the element's size.

Comment: Why would you do that rather then use the stm32f4xx.h header provided by ST?  Far less error prone, complete and simpler.

Comment: If you want to gain proficiency and don't want to use libraries, then just don use HAL, SPL, libopencm3 and whatever else you may find. But don't reinvent the wheel by not using CMSIS headers. There is absolutely nothing useful to learn by reimplementing headers that may be ~10000 lines long, really. You'll just quickly get bored and discouraged by such mundane tasks...

Comment: Any reason you don't use the `struct`s (types, macro-constants) defined in the header provided by the manufacturer? What if a registers is 16 or 8 bits only?

Comment: @FreddieChopin: I fully agree. But there are some problems with the register headers especially for the GPIOs: the hardware supports setting/clearing bits with a single 32 bit access (BSRR), the `struct`s only provide two 16 bit registers. This can create a race-.condition, spikes or possibly unnecessary overhead for locking. One should edit these headers to allow both: seperate 16 bit and 32 bit access.

Comment: @Olaf - most recent packages for F0, F1, F4 and F7 (all that I have on my hard drive) all have "BSRR" as single 32-bit register. If you need 16-bit access to that register there's no need to edit anything - casting and accessing via `[0]` or `[1]` is more than enough.

Comment: @FreddieChopin: Ok, it was the other way around (32 bit var, not two 16 bitters, I changed that years ago). Note that the cast invokes undefined behaviour, it violates effective type rule. Either way, you have to edit the header and use a `union { uint32_t BSRR; struct { uint16_t SET, CLR; }; };` to  be compliant and use all features of the hardware.

Comment: @Olaf - well, I don't think this (additional) violation is a problem here. Do remember, that the whole `GPIOx` struct pointer is defined more or less like `#define GPIOx (GPIO_TypeDef*)(0x40020000)`, so any additional type casting cannot really make that worse (;

Comment: @FreddieChopin: It invokes UB, and the compiler is free to do anything it wants. You'd be surprised what modern compilers like gcc do to optimise the code. Basically, if you rely on **undefined** behavior behavinmg _defined_, you are busted. If you came with such code for a review or audit, I'd refuse to continue until fixed correctly as every responsible embedded developer.

Comment: @Olaf - ok, let's leave UB behind. What's the exact problem with single BSRR? You want to set & clear some pins in a single operation - use every 32-bits. You want to only set or only clear some pins - use lower/upper 16-bits, leave remaining bits as 0. There's no possibility for any race (writing zero does nothing, BSx has priority over BRx). There's no overhead (writing 2 bytes will use the same number of cycles as writing 4). What you propose is a micro-optimization with zero effect on performance, but requiring modification of dozens of headers.

Comment: @FreddieChopin: It takes an extra cycle to mask the data. If you intend to set/clear specific bits, without spikes being relevant, you have to combine the two fields into a single register. And finally: that's not an optimisation, but how the hardware is intended to be used, too. It does not cost any additional code, just a correct declaration. Anonymous `struct` or `union` members are completely standard. For a header which should provide full access to the hardware, it is a flaw at best. (and that's not the only problem with the STM headers, just the one which came instantly to mind).

Comment: @FreddieChopin: After all, it is not clear what your problem is. I just mentioned one flaw in the header. It is quite common vendor-provided headers are bugged or flawed. I did no way say you were wrong about that bloatware STlib, etc. That is something which should be dumped asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the offsets are *byte*-based, it's *not* safe.

Adding something like `0x04` to a `uint32_t *reg_ptr` will cause the resulting address to refer to an offset that's four `uint32_t` values greater than what's in `reg_ptr` - not four *bytes* greater.

For example, adding `0x04` to the `uint32_t *` pointer value `0x40020400UL` will result in the actual pointer value `0x40020410UL` and **NOT** the expected `0x40020404UL`.

Comment: You don't want to say *not save*, but rather *wrong*

Comment: @tofro Well, the question is phrased as *"Is this practice unsafe?"*